# Get the future time as NSDate

Tags: objective-c, datetime, nscalendar

I have a date picker. After choosing a time from this I would like to get the dates and time of next 30 min and 1 hour.

How would I go about writing a method to take a date and time and return as two NSDates for the next 30 min and 1 hour from that date-time.

Example: I picked time 1:30 pm from date picker then I want to fetch next 30 min time and 1 hour time with there time set.

Can any one help on this ??

Comment: Use `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: `NSDateComponents` is useful to add intervals like a day or month, because these intervals do not have a fixed length. For adding 30 minutes, `dateByAddingTimeInterval` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
    components.minute = 30;
    components.hour = 1;
    NSDate *date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:< your date > options:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use dateByAddingTimeInterval method of [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Example :

```
NSDate *NextDateOneHour = [oldDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600];    //3600 second equivalent to 60 mins
NSDate *NextDateHalfAnHour = [oldDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:1800]; //1800 second equivalent to 30 mins
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setHour:1];

NSDate *afterHour = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date]  options:0];

[comps setMinute:30];

NSDate *afterHalfHour = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:[NSDate date]  options:0];
```